# Cannot explain why $_SESSION data is not passing along

Tags: php, session

I've had a rather out of the blue issue crop up with a project I've been working on for a while now.  I setup the sessions portion of my code over a month ago and this morning, when I logged into a test account on my code, it seems my $_SESSION data is no longer passing through between pages.

The login script is working fine and successfully triggers header.  But when I get to portalroom.php, print_r is generating "Array ( )".  portalroom.php starts with session_start().  I've also confirmed that register_globals is off in my php.ini.  At this point, I'm at a complete loss.

```
session_start();
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
    header("Location: portalroom.php");
    exit;
}   
$error = false;
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['username']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST['password']); 
  if(!$dbcon) {
    die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_error());
    $error = true;
    }
  if(!$error)   {
    $res=mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT userID,LoginName,Password FROM playerDB WHERE LoginName='$myusername'");
    if(!$res) {
        echo("Error:" . mysqli_error($dbcon));
        exit();
    }
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);

    if( $count == 1 && password_verify($mypassword, $row['Password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userID'];
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
        $_SESSION['created'] = time();
        header("Location: portalroom.php");
        exit;
    }   else { echo("Incorrect Username/Password"); }}}
```

(Edit)
Here's the top of the code for portalroom.php:

```
session_start();
include('session.php');
include('functions.php');   
include('sidebar.php'); 
include('scripts.php');
include('locationroom.php');
```

And because the actual code showing the $_SESSION data is being lost is on session.php, I've included the start of that:

```
// Are we logged in?  If no - Kick 'em out
print_r($_SESSION);
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { echo "we are here";
    // header("location:login.php");  
}
```

The relevant output from the code is: Array ( ) we are here

Comment: This is not right: `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {`

Comment: You are correct and I've fixed that.  Sadly it isn't fixing the issue at hand.  Thank you for that catch!

Comment: You probably need to show `portalroom.php` and add to it: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to check if it receives the session cookie, and sends it back with the next request. Also check that the session id inside the cookie stays the same.

Comment: I've played around a bit and I think the issue is with XAMPP itself.  I had to restart the server earlier today and it stopped working after that.   If I do the following:

  session_start();
 $_SESSION['test'] = "testsuccessful";
 session_write_close(); 
 print_r($_SESSION);
 header("Location: http://localhost:2357/kingdom/test2.php");


On test2.php the array comes back empty with this code:

 session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION);